# Windows 11 can't access certain folders

Tags: administrator, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I've just updated to windows 11 and I can't access certain folders. It denies me access sometimes but other times it just doesn't do anything.

The folder is `"C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Application Data"`
Second folder is `"C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\ElevatedDiagnostics"`

I have full control of this PC and am an admin. I was able to access this folder before I upgraded to windows 11

Comment: Permissions seem to have been lost. I suggest to give yourself full control to `C:\Users\adam` (not ownership).

Comment: Open File Explorer and navigate to the folders above. Double Click on the folder to open. See then if a dialogue box opens up that you can OK.   ..... If the upgrade went wrong somewhere, you may need to do a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Comment: I am going to be cautious answering this question due to spam it already received. The [ElevatedDiagnostics](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/elevateddiagnostics-help/8875ec4b-3157-4d87-b040-24e635a9cb7e) folder is not new.  It's been around since Windows Vista.  It probably is used by software connected to your printer. Likewise, `\Local\Application Data\` is also not new, likely contains user specific application data.  Unless you are getting errors associated with permissions you should leave that folder alone.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to access these folders?  There are numerous folders contained within Windows, that by default, even an Administrator cannot access (i.e. WindowsApps contained within Program Files). Are you trying to regain disk space because those folders likely contain very little data.