# Windows 11 can't access files copied from Windows 10, error 0x80070780

Tags: windows, windows-11

I've just moved my files from Windows 10 to Windows 11, and windows 11 can't access certain files, showing the following error 0x80070780: "the file cannot be accessed by the system"

[image]

The files previously were under the Desktop folder in Windows 10. To move them to my Windows 11 machine, on my Windows 10 machine, I copied the files from `C:\Users\myUser\Desktop` to `C:\fileToMove` so that they are no longer "protected" under the user's folders. Then, I **physically** moved the SSD from the Windows 10 machine to a newer Windows 11 machine.

On the Windows 11 machine, I can read other files and folders that were moved from `C:\Users\myUser\Desktop` to `C:\fileToMove` without any problem, but for a specific folder I'm getting the error.

The files seem to have a normal size, and folder structure is fine:

[image]

I deleted the `C:\Windows` folder on the SSD, so I can no longer access the files using Windows 10. On the Windows 11 machine, I tried to copy the files to another location using `Robocopy`, and it succeeded in accessing the files, but their size was 0KB:

[image]

I transferred ownership to this folder, and I also have "full control" permissions, but still getting the same error:

[image]

Advanced permissions:

[image]

I also tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1703802/windows-11-cant-access-certain-folders) SU question, but that didn't help.

How can I overcome this error and access the files?

Comment: Did you try booting in safe mode? Otherwise I would try booting on a live Linux distribution on a USB key and see if the files can accessed.

Comment: There are also some hints there: https://repairit.wondershare.com/file-repair/fix-error-0x80070780.html

Comment: Did it help to get a solution?

Comment: No solution as for now. This is really strange.

Comment: @PierU booting in safe mode didn't help